# Command to Change channel ID(spam_id)

Tags: discord.py

```py
spam_id = xxxxxx

@tasks.loop(seconds=0.2)
async def spammer(ctx):
  text_channel = client.get_channel(spam_id)

  if text_channel != None:

    num = random.randint(1,2)
    
    await text_channel.send(num)
    intervals = [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
    await asyncio.sleep(random.choice(intervals))
```

Comment: I want to make an command so tht I can change spam_id by commanding on discord

Answer (score 0):

Define `spam_id` as a global variable and access/modify it from a different function.

```py
spam_id = xxxxxx

@bot.command()
async def modify_spam_id(ctx, new_id : int):
    global spam_id
    spam_id = new_id 

@tasks.loop(seconds=0.2)
async def spammer(ctx):
    global spam_id
    text_channel = client.get_channel(spam_id)
    
    if text_channel != None:
    
    num = random.randint(1,2)
    
    await text_channel.send(num)
    intervals = [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
    await asyncio.sleep(random.choice(intervals))
```

Comment: now what to do for command?

Comment: @sanchitjaiswal I've edited my answer a little. For an example, if your command prefix is `!`, you would call the command as follows: `!modify_spam_id <channel_id>`.

Comment: Can u also tell me how to make it save everytime I use cmnd